# In app purchase without Xcode (Apple app store)

Tags: macos, app-store, in-app-purchase, common-lisp, ccl

We are trying to put our app in the apple app store and would like to add in app purchases but unfortunately our app is not created with Xcode.  We use an implementation of common lisp called CCL which includes an objective C bridge to access the Cocoa API.  This is all fine and good except after reading through the StoreKitGuide I see that we are supposed to link again the StoreKit.framework in order to add a store to my app.

This presents a problem because we are not using XCode to create our app.  Is it possible to add in app purchase to your app if we are not using in app purchases?  I realize that most people on here will not be using common lisp but I was wondering if they could offer any insight into how one could enable in app purchases without Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `(OBJC:LOAD-FRAMEWORK "SKRequest" :storekit)` succeed? Or perhaps `(OBJC:LOAD-FRAMEWORK "StoreKit" :cocoa)`?

If not, you might have to create the interfaces yourself:  http://ccl.clozure.com/manual/chapter13.5.html#Creating-new-interface-directories

Comment: Yes, it was an issue of the interface to being create but it has been added to the lates trunk now.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an Objective C bridge, them this bridge will need to be modified or updated to support the frameworks you require and whose support is not currently included on the bridge.  Recompiling the bridge code likely will require Xcode plus the bridge source code.